# ElasticSearch: What is the param limit in painless scripting?

Tags: elasticsearch

**I will have documents with the following data -**
 1. id
 2. user_id
 3. online_hr
 4. offline_hr

**My use case is the following -**
I wish to sort the users who are **active** using `online_hr` field,
While I want to sort the users who are **inactive** using the `offline_hr` field.

I am planning to use ElasticSearch painless script for this use case,
I will have using 2 arrays of `online_user_list` and `offline_user_list` into the script params,
And I plan to compare each document's `user_id`,
if it is present in the either of the params lists and sort accordingly.

I want to know if there is any limit to the param object,
As the userbase may be in 100s of thousands,
And if passing 2 lists of that size in the ES scripting params would be troublesome?
And if there is any better approach?

**Query to add data -**

```
POST /products/_doc/1
{
  "id":1,
  "user_id" : "1",
  "online_hr" : "1",
  "offline_hr" : "2"
}
```

**Sample data -**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "user_id" : "1",
          "online_hr" : "1",
          "offline_hr" : "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Mapping -**

```
{
  "products" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "offline_hr" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "online_hr" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "user_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1566466257331",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "g2F3UlxQSseHRisVinulYQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7020099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "products"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found Painless scripts have a default size limit of `65,535 bytes`,
while the ElasticSearch compiler had a limit of `16834 characters`

**Reference -**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-walkthrough.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html

Comment: Sorry, but could not get the question correctly. Can you please add mapping, a sample document and the script you tried to give a clear picture

Comment: @Richa I've added the Document and Mapping, Script I plan to write after checking if the solution is feasible